# Get sales orders from Amazon MWS scratchpad via API

Tags: postman, soapui, amazon-mws, sap-erp

My mission is to get Amazon sales orders out for a given time period and post these into a SAP ECC back end via SAP PI. I've managed to get the MWS scratchpad working and am a bit stuck as to how i would put the data from the scratch pad into postman or SOAPUI.

1. I don't know the endpoint for Amazon MWS to find the API or WSDL structure - where to send the call. How can I find out?
2. how do i know what information to pass into what areas of the SOAPUI or postman tools?
3. How do i get the WSDL for the MWS response call so i can export it and import that structure into sap to save me building a massive response structure?

This is my mws scratchpad:

[image: MWS]

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need is right here: [Orders API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=orders&group=orders&version=latest)

It tells you your endpoint, your operations, and your request and response parameters.  What language do you use?  If you use PHP, C#, or Java, there are client libraries that do all this for you, just plug in your account info.

For the ListOrders operation specifically, it's right here - [ListOrders](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html).

The response format is explained [here](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ResponseFormat.html).

You also need to calculate a signature, something that scratchpad and the MWS client libraries will do for you.  Not sure how you can do that from Postman.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your assistance [image]again . The scratchapd works a dream. Yes, i am not sure how postman will do this either. I am calling from SAP PI, presumably some code will have to be written in java to handle the calculation of the signature and timestamp - i get the current error when posting in postman:

Comment: scratchpad and postman should be used just for development and testing, so once you understand the process, use the Java client library as part of your workflow.  It will handle all the heavy lifting for you, including the signature/timestamp and the serialization too.

Comment: Thanks Scott - yeah my boss did the Java bit.. Just doing the mapping in PI now.

Comment: great to hear!!